# Pacco vs Confezione: sinonimi?

Tags: word-meaning, word-choice, synonym

C'è una differenza tra "pacco" e "confezione" oppure possiamo considerarli sinonimi?
Un pacco di biscotti = una confezione di biscotti

Comment: Condivido il commento di @Gae.S. e la/lo inviterei a farne una risposta. Mi limiterei a sottolineare che, visto che sia “confezione” che “pacco” hanno anche altri sfumature di significato (confezioni per uomo, pacco postale etc.), non sono del tutto intercambiabili ed è bene sincerarsi quale sia più adatto al contesto.